# Assigning pointer to already assigned pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to figure out some as I suppose silly mistake in my code but I am not sure if what I've found can be the one so I'd like SO community to tell if my thinking is correct.

At some point in my code I am moving on a tree to do calculations with each element. Basic code looks like this:

```
Quadtree* current_box = this->parent_group->GetParent();
Quadtree* previous_box = this->parent_group;
while(true)
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
            {
                if(current_box->trees[i][j][k] == previous_box)
                    continue;
                else
                    //do some math
            }
        }
    }

    previous_box = current_box;
    if(current_box->GetParent()==nullptr)
    {
        break;
    }
    current_box = current_box->GetParent();
}
```

and later in other place in code when I want to assign value to one of this object's field everything breaks down and there is some indication regarding segmentation fault on this:

`if(current_box->trees[i][j][k] == previous_box)` line.

What I suppose might be happening here is that those two lines

```
previous_box = current_box;
current_box = current_box->GetParent();
```

are messing everything. Because if I am correct I am not assigning new pointer value to `current_box` and `previous_box` but I am assigning those values to pointers already there, so I have some mess with addresses. Do I think correctly?

In other words am I assigning `this->parent_group->GetParent()` to the address of `this->parent_group`?

**EDIT:**

I see that my question might be not clear, so let me rephrase it - after

```
    previous_box = current_box;
    //...
    current_box = current_box->GetParent();
```

Will I have under `previous_box` value from `current_box`, or will I assign value from `current_box` to `this->parent_group`?

Comment: Your terminology is unclear. "I am assigning those values to pointers already there". What would that mean? You assign *values* to *variables*. Your variables are current_box and previous_box.

Comment: `Do I think correctly?` Probably not. But please show more relevant code.

Comment: It's hard, if not impossible, to suggest anything useful without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You never verify that current_box os not a null pointer. Unless you can prove that it is never null, dereferencing it is inherently dangerous. Why not loop `while (current_box)` and eliminate mid-loop checks and breaks?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not assigning new pointer value to current_box and previous_box but I am assigning those values to pointers already there, so I have some mess with addresses. Do I think correctly?

You're assign the pointer value. The value that was in the pointers is gone after the assignment. After the two assignements, `previous_box` points to the object that `current_box` used to point to and `current_box` points to the parent of that object.

> In other words am I assigning this->parent_group->GetParent() to the address of this->parent_group?

`this->parent_group->GetParent()` is a function. The value returned by the function is not modified by the assignments.

> segmentation fault on this: `if(current_box->trees[i][j][k] == previous_box)` line.

The most likely reasons for that are: `this`, `this->parent_group`, `this->parent_group->GetParent()` or `current_box->trees` (for any value of `current_box`) does not point to a valid object or array. Or One of `i`, `j` or `k` is out of bounds of the array.